# Summing transactions using DAX functions in Excel PowerPivot

Tags: excel, database-design, powerpivot, dax

I have a table in my PowerPivot data model called *Orders* which stores all our order records, each row is a unique order record and their are no duplicates.

I have a second table in my data model called *Transactions* - this table does not have any unique columns however it does have a column called '**OrderID**' which is related to the orders stored in the '**Orders**' table. A single OrderID may have multiple transactions against it.

I want to add a calculated column to the *Orders* table which sums the value of all the transactions in '*Transactions*' which have a '**OrderID**' equal to the '**OrderID**' in '**Orders**'

Before I was using PowerPivot this was simple, I used a **SUMIFS** function, this however is not available in PowerPivot, and building a relationship between the two tables does not work because their are multiple transactions for each Order.

Can anyone recommend I can achieve the same SUMIFS result in PowerPivot using a DAX syntax?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm updating this to say that I was being a complete muppet.  The reason that my relationships weren't working was because my column headers had somehow been duplicated and was appearing a record elsewhere in the table.

As soon as I removed this and created a relationship between the tables as above and the PivotTables worked absolutely fine.

Apologies for wasting anyones time.